# Range Slider Currency - Converter número em valor em real (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Fala galera, sou iniciante em javascript.
Estou criando (ou tentando criar) um `range` que passe um valor e imprima o valor conforme a barra é arrastada, e até aí está funcionando tudo bem.

Mas o valor vem em número inteiro, e eu já tentei várias coisas e não consigo converter esse número para reais.

O script é esse.
A variavel range pega o valor do input `range`, e a impressão faz o óbvio kkk imprime na tag `span`

```js
var range = document.getElementById("range");

var impressao = document.getElementById("impressao");

impressao.innerHTML = range.value;

range.oninput = function() {
  impressao.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<h2><span id="impressao"></span></h2>
<input type="range" value="500" min="500" max="10000" step="100" id="range">
```

alguém conseguiria me ajudar? por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.toLocaleString()` para formatar o valor em moeda do Real e dispare o evento `input` ao carregar a página para já mostrar o valor formatado:

```js
var range = document.getElementById("range");

var impressao = document.getElementById("impressao");

impressao.innerHTML = range.value;

range.oninput = function() {
  impressao.innerHTML = parseInt(this.value).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
}

// disparar o evento manualmente
var event = new CustomEvent("input");
range.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<h2><span id="impressao"></span></h2>
<input type="range" value="500" min="500" max="10000" step="100" id="range">
```